# How to call external url?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, url, angular-ui-router

I am making an application using angular 6, and here i am having two urls,

Where **url 1** is http://authentication.hello.com and 
**url 2** is http://application.hello.com

Here if the user is loggen in via url 1 will only able to redirect to url 2.

Whereas if the user gives directly the url as http://application.hello.com , it should redirect to http://authentication.hello.com for login.

For which i have used the following,

```
if (localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn") === "true") {
  return true;
} else {
  window.location.href = "authentication.hello.com";
}
```

Here i have used

```
window.location.href = "authentication.hello.com";
```

to redirect to the authentication if not logged in.

But if the user gives the url directly as http://application.hello.com, then it is displaying as, http://application.hello.com/authentication.hello.com, Here its getting added to the given url but the thing i am in the need is, it should **remove** http://application.hello.com and there should be only url as http://authentication.hello.com where user can see the login screen.

For `window.location.replace("authentication.hello.com")` also the same result of http://application.hello.com/authentication.hello.com is coming whereas i am in the need to load the url `authentication.hello.com` alone **without** `application.hello.com` if not loggedin.

Kindly help me to achieve it using pure javascript or typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Full URL to set value in window.location.href :

```
window.location.href = "http://authentication.hello.com";
```